# how to check wether the statement executes with error or without error?

Tags: php

i want some kind of error handling that set a boolean variable false if the statement executes with error
or set boolean true if it run without error

in my condition my code is

```
$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

$statement = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO userft (name, username, pasword, email, contact, age) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$statement->bind_param('ssssii', $name, $username,$pasword,$email,$contact, $age);
$statement->execute();

if(!($statement->execute())){   //<----- in replace of this statement?<-----
$response["success"]=false;}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php

Comment: `$statement->execute()` when execting an INSET/UPDATE/DELETE already returned a Boolean True or False

Comment: i think that is for checking error in database connection
if i m wrong please modify my code :) thanks

Comment: ___Bit Note___ You are executing the `$statement->execute();` **twice** in your code. WHY

Comment: @RiggsFolly i want to change'    if(!($statement->execute())) 'this line to some error handling

Comment: See @RamRaider answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign the `execute` statement return value to a variable you can test for success/failure.

```
$response = array('success'=>false);


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO userft (name, username, pasword, email, contact, age) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
/* First test that the statement was prepared successfully */
if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssii', $name, $username,$pasword,$email,$contact, $age);

    /* assign return value of execute to a variable */
    $status = $stmt->execute();

    /* use variable to determine response */
    $response["success"]=$status ? true : false;
}
```

You can read more about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) on the [PHP site](http://php.net/)

Comment: It would be nice to include a link to [mysqli_prepare documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 1):

The execute statement returns boolean, so you are doing the right thing; you could assign the result to a variable:

```
$success = $statement->execute();
if ($success) {
    echo "Inserted!";
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong!";
}
```

If in doubt, check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-execute.php).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$statement->execute();
if ($statement->affected_rows()) {
         //success
} else {
   die('execute() failed: ' . $mysqli->error);
}
```